# How do I get a user's bio with the SE API?

Tags: support, api-v2, users

Am I just missing something here or is there not a way to retrieve a user's bio with the SE API? I looked at [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) under the "Users" section, but I didn't find anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "bio" you mean the ***about me*** field, right? ...

[image: About-me field]

Any path that returns [a *user* object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) will return the `about_me` property, but this is not returned by default.  You have to use a [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that has `about_me` enabled.

For example, here is a query to get your "About me" on *stackapps*:

[users-by-ids#ids=8109&filter=!.2mo6GlnpFPFeBKnaz&site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=8109&filter=!.2mo6GlnpFPFeBKnaz&site=stackapps&run=true)

---

An easy way to create a filter is to use the filter-edit tool, on [the appropriate doc page for the path you are using](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids). :

[image: Filter tool]